# MBProgressHUD UI not responding

Tags: ios, user-interface, mbprogresshud

I found my UI to be unresponsive while using the MBProgress HUD, while debugging on device it shows me the message "wait_fences failed to receive reply". I think i am using MBProgressHUD in wrong way. can someone please tell me what's the best way to use MBProgressHUD in following scenario.

```
if (!self.detailController) {

            DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
            detailVC.view.autoresizingMask = baseView.autoresizingMask; //(baseView Alerady added on xib for orientation purpose)
            self.detailController = detailVC;
            [detailVC release];
        }
        [self.view addSubview: self.detailController.view]; //Removing detailController.view before calling to this function.
        [self.detailController makeServiceCall];

        -(void)makeServiceCall
        {
            //HUD is class level variable 
            if (!HUD) {
                HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view.window];    
                HUD.dimBackground = YES;
                [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];
                HUD.labelText = @"";
            }
            //Showing the HUD progress bar
            [HUD show:YES];

            //Async call code for service call, once connection end hiding the HUD. 
        }

        -(void)parsingFinished
        {
            //Data handling goes here..
            [HUD hide:YES];
        }
```

I researched on the UI unresponsiveness and found that HUD needs to be shown in viewDidAppear method, but i am adding view as subview and because of that viewDidAppear does not being called.

If I am removing HUD from my app, it works very well, so i am sure the app is unresponsive because of the usage of HUD in wrong way.
I have done this at lot many places of my application. need best solution that i can apply.

Answer (score 0):

MBProgressHUD blocks interaction with the UI while it's visible. I forget off the top of my head if this is configurable but blocking the UI of its parent view is its default state. Especially if you're adding it to the window instead of a subview.